# Can we get all elements stored in a mapping in the contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, mapping

Can we get all elements stored in  a mapping in the contract using web3.js ?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Mappings do not store their keys, only the value which is stored at the state memory address calculated by a sha3 hash of the the key itself. Any lookup into a mapping has to provide that original key or be able to calculate it.

This means that a contract has no way of discovering mapped data without assistance which can lead to orphaned data bloating the state database, particularly after a contract is `selfdestructed`.

I strongly believe that contract authors should be responsible in regards to garbage collection and write *total discoverable data* contracts in which all data can be discovered and deleted if and when required.  For mappings, that requires key storage or calculation in some way or another.

#### Look Up Tables

The simplest pattern to key storage is a simple lookup table:

```
mapping (address => uint) public balances;
address[] public addressLUT;

// Requires a public getter for array size
function size() public returns (uint) {
    return addressLUT.length;
}
```

To which the associated JS could iterate across the whole mapping:

```
for(i = 0; i < k.size(); i++) {
    someFunc( k.balances(k.addressLUT(i)) );
}
```

One drawback with arrays is they can get gappy over time when elements are deleted.  This can lead to unpredictable gas costs if a contract itself has to search through those gaps.

#### Linked List Indexes

Another approach is linked list indexes.

```
mapping (address => address) llIndex;
mapping (address => uint) public balances;

function add(address _addr) public 
{
    llIndex[_addr] = llIndex[0x0];
    llIndex[0x0] = _addr;
}
```

Here we insert address keys at `llIndex[0x0]` when we create a new balance.  We can then iterate the entire `balance` mapping by stepping through the `llIndex` mapping starting a key `0x0` and given the first node points to `0x0` by default, we don't need a separate store for size bounding:

```
var current = k.llIndex(0);
while (current) {
    console.log( k.balances(current) );
    current = k.llIndex(current);
}
```

Link lists don't suffer the same potential gappiness as arrays and so don't waste machine cycles looking for valid data. However, deleting from a singular linked list does require a search to find the parent node.

```
function remove(address _addr) {
    address parent;

    // Warning: unbounded gas loop
    while (llIndex[parent] != _addr) parent = llIndex[parent];

    llIndex[parent] = llIndex[ llIndex[parent]];
    delete llIndex[_addr];
    delete balances[_addr];
}
```

This is fine when you're confident the data set won't grow to a size where a potential search uses unacceptable amounts of gas, or causes OOG  altogether.  Here 'unacceptable' is a bit subjective, so I'll quantify it with "more gas than the cost of a storage slot" which is 20000 for a new one and 5000 from the second and dealer ;).

#### Double Linked List indexes

In such cases it's worth removing search loops altogether at the expense of an extra storage slot per indexed element.  For this we can use a *Double Linked List* index using a nested `bool` mapping for bidirectional links where we interpret `PREV == false` and `NEXT == true`):

```
mapping(address => ( mapping(bool => address) ) dllIndex;
mapping(address => uint) balances;

function add(address _addr)
{
    // Link the new node 
    dllIndex[_addr][PREV] = 0x0;
    dllIndex[_addr][NEXT] = dllIndex[0x0][NEXT];

    // Insert the new node
    dllIndex[dllIndex[0x0][NEXT]][PREV] = _addr;
    dllIndex[0x0][NEXT] = _addr;
}

function remove(address _addr)
{
    // Stitch the neighbours together
    dllIndex[ dllIndex[_addr][PREV] ][NEXT] = dllIndex[_addr][NEXT];
    dllIndex[ dllIndex[_addr][NEXT] ][PREV] = dllIndex[_addr][PREV];

    // Delete state storage
    delete dllIndex[_addr][PREV];
    delete dllIndex[_addr][NEXT];
    delete balances[_addr];
}
```

We now have a directly addressable and fully iterable storage structure, which is not just a *Double Linked List* but a *Circular Double Linked List* by default with the head at `0x0`.  This gives us two very desirable properties for free...

#### FIFO and FILO Queues

*First In First Out* (FIFO) and *First In Last Out* (FILO) queues are a very common concept in computing.  FIFO can be used for task queues while FILO is also used for memory 'stacks'.

FIFO's can be used in any contracts that require atomic sequential order processing.  Here a new order is simply inserted *previous* to the head, while the oldest order is simply taken from *next* to the head.  No search loops required.

If you think these structures might be useful, check out my [Circular Double Linked List Index Library](https://github.com/o0ragman0o/LibCLL) which is used by my [Intrinsically Tradable Tokens (ITT)](https://github.com/o0ragman0o/ITT) contract.

Comment: Should it be `address[] public addressLUT;` instead of `addresses[] public addressLUT;`?

Comment: Would it also possible to get the length of a double linked list index? And how would you do that? Thanks

Comment: My [LibCLL](https://github.com/o0ragman0o/LibCLL/blob/master/LibCLL.sol#L50) has a `sizeOf()` function which starts at head (always index 0) and counts steps until it sees the head again.

Comment: Should `llIndex[0x0]` first initialized, what does it map to at the beginning or should we can see it as null value ? It this the correct way to visualize it?: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/f45009418b192da25769ce3fa9d682ab.  As I understand the algorithm always pushes new element into head of the linked list  @o0ragman0o

Comment: All Solidity storage is already implicitly initialised to zero and there is no 'null' data type to indicate uninitialised storage.  This means there's no way to differentiate uninitialised data slots from intentionally zero value data. By treating the zero index as null and keeping it data free, we have a hook into the circle of the linked list (the 'head').  It also means that any attempt to reference the link of an uninitialised node will just point to the head.

Comment: Did you have chance to see the gas cost for each function such as `add()` or `remove()`?  @o0ragman0o

Comment: Been a long time since I visited this code and there've been multiple forks adjusting gas dynamics since. [This doc](https://github.com/o0ragman0o/LibCLL#mutations-to-state) describes the number of state mutations my library takes.

Comment: There's an extra parentheses in dllIndex

Answer (score 9):

You have to track an index of the elements you stored in the mapping.

Some solution patterns here: [Are there well-solved and simple storage patterns for Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity)

Hope it helps.