# Faster way of getting contract property in Web3js

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js

Using web3js `0.20.2` and `truffle-contract`, I have been getting public properties of my contract by doing

```
Foo.deployed().then(function(instance) { 
    instance.rate.call().then((r) => {
        console.log(r)
    })
});
```

Came across a less verbose way of writing the same code [[here]](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/15341/19219), which does something like

```
Foo.deployed().then(function(instance) { 
    console.log(instance.rate())
});
```

In the linked webpage, the author suggested the following where `k` is the contract instance:

```
for(i = 0; i < k.size(); i++) {
    someFunc( k.balances(k.addressLUT(i)) );
}
```

to avoid

```
for(i = 0; i < k.size(); i++) {
    k.addressLUT(i).call().then((res) => {
        k.balances(res).call().then((res) => {
            someFunc(res)
        })
    })
}
```

However when I try out the second method, why is `instance.name()` giving me a promise, similar to using `instance.name.call()`? Shouldnt we get the value immediately without waiting for the Promise to be resolved?

**instance.rate()**

```
> instance.rate()

Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: BigNumber
```

**instance.rate.call()**

```
> instance.rate.call()

Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: BigNumber
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`truffle-contract` treats constant method calls as promises to be consistent in it's library API design with transactional method calls. The best wait to simulate synchronous calls is to use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) when dealing with JavaScript promises.

Here's an example:

```
async function example () {
    const k = await Foo.deployed()

    for (let i = 0; i < k.size(); i++) {
        someFunc(await k.balances(await k.addressLUT(i).call()))
    }
}
```

If your solidity method is using the `constant` modifier than you don't need to use `.call()` in your JavaScript. You should always use `constant` if your function doesn't modify any `storage` state because it tells the compiler that it'll only perform read actions therefore it infers no gas costs.