# Default getter and setter for mapping in solidity

Tags: solidity, truffle, storage, mapping, struct

In my smart contract, I have a public mapping as `mapping (uint=>User) public users` where `User` is a `Struct`. Is there any way to get the values of this mapping using a default getter?

For Example : If we have `public uint count`, we can simply call it by using `Object.count`. Is it possible with mapping as well?

Please help!

Answer (score 4):

First of all, there is no such thing as default setter (mentioned in title of your question).

Now about default getter.  [Solidity documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.7/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters) gives the following example:

```
struct Data {
    uint a;
    bytes3 b;
    mapping (uint => uint) map;
}
mapping (uint => mapping(bool => Data[])) public data;
```

will generate the following getter:

```
function data(uint arg1, bool arg2, uint arg3) public returns (uint a, bytes3 b) {
    a = data[arg1][arg2][arg3].a;
    b = data[arg1][arg2][arg3].b;
}
```

So, default getter returns not the structure, but rather tuple of all atomic structure fields.

In your case getter will look like:

```
function users (uint id) public returns (/* all atomic fields of User structure */)
```

Answer (score 1):

You get a function that takes an index argument. It returns the scalar values in the struct, so everything that isn't itself a mapping or an array.

For instance:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract StuctsGetter {

    struct MyStruct {
        uint a;
        bytes32 b;
        mapping(address => bool) active;
        bytes32[] keys;
    }

    mapping(uint => MyStruct) public myStructs;

    function setMyStruct(uint index, uint a, bytes32 b) public {
        MyStruct storage m = myStructs[index];
        m.a = a;
        m.b = b;
    }

}
```

You can call `instance.myStructs(uint)` to fetch the mapped struct at a certain index. It will return `a` and `b` but not `active` or `keys`.

*Avoid a head-scratcher:* If there isn't at least one scalar value (i.e. the `struct` is made entirely of mappings and/or arrays) then the compiler won't know how to construct the "free" getter. It will fail in a confusing way.

To set/get the indexed values in a mapped struct, write your own functions.

```
function appendKeyToMyStruct(uint _myStruct, address key) public ... {
  myStructs[_myStruct].keys.push(key);
}

function getMyStructKey(uint _myStruct, uint row) public ... {
  return myStructs[_myStruct].keys[row];
}
```

These patterns may give you some ideas: [Are there well-solved and simple storage patterns for Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity)

A little info about the storage pointer used in the example: https://blog.b9lab.com/storage-pointers-in-solidity-7dcfaa536089

Hope it helps.

Comment: but what if I want values from all mapped structs and not from certain index

Comment: That would involve enumerating all the mapped structs which is not possible. Mappings don't store the keys. "Mapped Struct with Index" in the link I shared describes a way of coping with this limitation by keeping a list yourself. You'll find lots of Q/A here about iterating mapped values and why it is not possible, like this: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15337/can-we-get-all-elements-stored-in-a-mapping-in-the-contract/15341#15341

Comment: I would add that it is seldom necessary to return a complete array, but that's common orientation for devs who are new to the space. A complete justification would take too much space for here, but suffice it to say that gas cost will increase (`O(n)`) which we do not want, and client software can a) listen to events and b) iterate, therefore c) "return all" would be repetitive and costly in most cases.