# How can I get this mapping function in an interface?

Tags: mapping, pancakeswap, interfaces, abiencoderv2

I have this mapping in a smart contract:

```
mapping (uint256 => mapping (address => UserInfo)) public userInfo;
```

I want to call this in a interface like function view returns:

Can someone tell me if like this:

```
function poolInfo(uint256 _pid, address _dres) external view returns (IMasterChef.UserInfo memory);
```

Am i wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Default getter and setter for mapping in solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/67832/default-getter-and-setter-for-mapping-in-solidity)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.